# Ruby - 2 ends for an if statement

Tags: ruby

The following is a coding sample:

```
  d(val)
   if !(val.is_a? Fixnum)
      "#{val} is not an integer"
   elsif val % 2 == 0    
      "#{val} is even"
   else             
      "#{val} is odd"
   end
end
```

What I don't understand is why there are two 'end's. I think there should only be one 'end' to complete the if statement. Please explain.

Comment: Because that is not valid Ruby code.

Answer (score 1):

Either you are missing a `def` there:

```
def d(val)
   if !(val.is_a? Fixnum)
      "#{val} is not an integer"
   elsif val % 2 == 0    
      "#{val} is even"
   else             
      "#{val} is odd"
   end
end
```

or it is invalid Ruby code.

In the first case, the second `end` would close the method definition while the first would close the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

There should only be one end;

The first line looks like a definition of a method

```
def even_or_odd(val)
  if ...
    ...
  end
end
```

The second end would close the definition.